# Java Swing, application or applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet

If I want to write a GUI program using Swing, my understanding is that I can either write a Swing desktop application, or write a Swing-based applet (which I can run using appletviewer or a browser). But it's not clear to me which one to use.

I don't have a particular program in mind; I'm trying to understand generally which is better under what circumstances. Any clarification on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applets are meant to be executed inside a browser and have a few more restrictions to ensure that users can run any applet without major risk. While the concept of applets was revolutionary when it was introduced, it has never had as much success as it deserved. These days, applets are quite an exception.

Desktop apps have less restrictions than applets and in most cases it is probably what you want.

If you want easy distribution of your app, you should also have a look at [Java Web Start](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml) though again, it does not have the traction it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better or worse in this regard because an applet is run with Java Web Start using [JNLP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-137531.html) which is a way to **deploy** Java technology based applications.

It entirely depends on the intended architecture, distribution, security considerations, use cases, etc. of an application which way is optimal.

Web Start requires software on top of JRE but it is included in the default Java Runtime package since version 1.4.2.

Comment: *"There is no better or worse in this regard"*  Applets are a deployment and maintenance nightmare, so I'd definitely consider them 'worse'.